# Factoring cubic polynomials with missing terms.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I am working on a linear algebra problem where I have to diagonalize a matrix. The characteristic equation is $-\lambda ^3 - 3 \lambda^2 + 4$. I need to factor this in order to solve part of the problem but I was never taught how to factor polynomial with missing terms. I have tried using synthetic division and got $(\lambda-1)(- \lambda^2-4)$. The example in the books says the factored form is $-(\lambda-1)(\lambda+2)^2$. Am I on the right track? I can't see what the next step would be.

Comment: Rewrite the polynomial as $-\lambda ^3 -3\lambda^2 + 0 \lambda + 4$ and use the standard factorisation techniques.

Comment: What do you mean by standard factorisation techniques?

Comment: You said you were never taught how to factor with missing terms. By adding the term $0 \lambda$ you can treat it as if there are no missing terms.

Comment: If you did the synthetic division correctly, you should have gotten $-\lambda^3 - 3\lambda^2 + 4 = (\lambda-1)(-\lambda^2-4\lambda-4) = -(\lambda-1)(\lambda^2+4\lambda+4)$. Now, just factor the quadratic.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thank you! I forgot to include the 0 coefficient when I used synthetic division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check which divisors of the constant term, $4$, are the roots of $-\lambda^3-3 \lambda^2+4=0$. Let $a$ be this divisor(if there are more than one, take one of them), then apply the Euclidean division of $-\lambda^3-3 \lambda^2+4$ and $\lambda-a$.

Then you get $-\lambda^3-3 \lambda^2+4=(\lambda-a) \cdot q$, where $q$ is a second degree polynomial, which you can find its roots using the disciminant.

Comment: For the divisors of 4, do I have to check both positive and negatives? And is Euclidean division the same as synthetic division?

Comment: Yes, both positive and negative...You could also use the synthetic division.